# Creating Test Class for VF Page Controller

Tags: visualforce, deployment, code-coverage, standardcontroller, inline-visualforce

Having trouble creating a test class for my VF Page Controller I am trying to develop.

I have created an inbound change set in my Production, and an outbound in my Sandbox. Now I am at the step of going from 0% code coverage to at least a 75% code coverage, and not having done this before, I am having issues.

Here is my VF Page I am attempting to implement with a controller. It is a VF page simply with an output from a custom text field to be shown in a separate section in my Account Layout, BUT I NEEDED INLINE EDIT FUNCTIONALITY for this custom field referenced in my VF page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" 
extensions="inlineEditControl">
       <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlock mode="inlineEdit">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Delete" id="deleteBut"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Edit" id="editBut" />
                <apex:commandButton id="saveBut" value="Save"/>
                <apex:commandButton id="cancelBut" value="Cancel"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageblock >
         Click here to enable inline editing     <apex:inputCheckbox >
                <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!SetInlineEdit}" reRender="pgblck"/>
              </apex:inputCheckbox>
            </apex:pageblock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="pgblck">
                <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Master_Notes__c}">
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveBut, cancelBut"  event="ondblclick" hideOnEdit="deleteBut,editbut" rendered="{!InLineFlag}"/>
                </apex:outputField>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

So I am trying to DEPLOY/TEST this controller:

```
Public with sharing class inlineEditControl {
Public Boolean InLineFlag{get;set;}
    public inlineEditControl(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
     InLineFlag = false;
    }
   Public void SetInlineEdit(){
    if(InLineFlag == false)
      InLineFlag = true;
    else
     InLineFlag = false;
   }
}
```

And so, I am attempting to write a test class to achieve this minimum code coverage. Thus far, this is what I have:

```
 @isTest
    public class testInlineEditControl {
    static testMethod void testInlineEditControlCreate(){

        inlineEditControl a = new inlineEditControl(name='Test');
        Test.startTest();
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(a);
        inlineEditControl q = inlineEditControl(sc);
        system.assert(q != null);
        Test.stopTest();

        }
    }
```

My issues lie between the start/stop Test lines - I am confused as to triggers/actions and how to achieve code coverage in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Adding these lines to your test should cause all the remaining lines to be covered:

```
System.assertEquals(false, q.InLineFlag);
q.SetInlineEdit();
System.assertEquals(true, q.InLineFlag);
q.SetInlineEdit();
System.assertEquals(false, q.InLineFlag);
```

For test coverage, you need to think about the major paths through the code and invoke methods and set fields that cause those paths to be taken. You should then also assert the results so your test is checking the behaviour.