# Compile Error: expecting a semi-colon, found 'pageRef' on a @isTest

Tags: apex, unit-test, visualforce-component, class

I'm getting compile error on line 6 column 22 on my test class

```
@isTest
public class ControllerProposalConvertViewTest {

static testMethod void convert(){
    Proposal p = new Proposal (p.Name = 'Test Name', p.Already_Converted__c = 'Not Converted',p.Property__c = 'a007A000001C6CM', p.Zoning__c = 'Zone',p.Lease_Type__c = 'Monthly', p.Lease_Notes__c = 'Ground Lease',p.Lot_Size__c = 100.00,p.Lot__c = 50.00,p.Cap_Rate__c = 512.75,p.Year_Built__c = '1975',p.Term__c = 456,p.NOI__c = 123.12,p.Years_Remaining__c = 10.50,p.Lease_Commencement_Date__c = date.Today(),p.Rent_Commencement_Date__c = date.Today(),p.Lease_Expiration_Date__c = date.Today(),p.Square_Footage__c = 50000),
    PageReference pageRef = Page.ProposalConvertView; 
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef); 
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',p.Id); 
    ControllerProposalConvertView cont = new ControllerProposalConvertView (new Proposal__c()); 
    cont.convert();
    }
   }
```

Any advice?

This is my Apex Controller

```
public class ControllerProposalConvertView {
public Id pId;
public String convertedAccountId;

public ControllerProposalConvertView(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
pId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');
System.Debug('#######leadId:' + pId);
}


public PageReference convert(){

try{
Proposal__c p = [SELECT Id, name, Already_Converted__c, Property__c,   Square_Footage__c, Lot_Size__c, Lot__c, Cap_Rate__c, Year_Built__c, Zoning__c, Term__c, Lease_Type__c, NOI__c, Lease_Commencement_Date__c, Rent_Commencement_Date__c, Lease_Expiration_Date__c, Years_Remaining__c, Lease_Notes__c FROM Proposal__c WHERE Id=:pId LIMIT 1];

if (p.Already_Converted__c  =='Not Converted'){
Listing__c c=new Listing__c(Name=p.Name, Property__c=p.Property__c, Square_Footage__c=p.Square_Footage__c,  Lot_Size__c=p.Lot_Size__c, Lot__c=p.Lot__c, Cap_Rate__c=p.Cap_Rate__c, Year_Built__c=p.Year_Built__c, Zoning__c=p.Zoning__c, Term__c=p.Term__c, Lease_Type__c=p.Lease_Type__c, NOI__c=p.NOI__c, Lease_Commencement_Date__c=p.Lease_Commencement_Date__c, Rent_Commencement_Date__c=p.Rent_Commencement_Date__c, Lease_Expiration_Date__c=p.Lease_Expiration_Date__c,      Years_Remaining__c=p.Years_Remaining__c, Lease_Notes__c=p.Lease_Notes__c);
System.Debug('#######c :' + c );
insert c;
p.Already_Converted__c='Converted';
update p;
convertedAccountId = c.Id;
System.Debug('#######convertedAccountId :' + convertedAccountId );
}

else{
        String sServerName =         ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host');
sServerName = 'https://'+sServerName+'/';
PageReference retPage = new PageReference(sServerName +           '/apex/ProposalConvertView2?id='+ pId); 
retPage.setRedirect(true);
System.Debug('#######ALREADYCONVERTED' );

return retPage;
}

}

catch(Exception e){
    System.Debug('#######Error  - Exception [' + e.getMessage() + ']');
    return null;
}
String sServerName = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host');
sServerName = 'https://'+sServerName+'/';
System.Debug('#######sServerName :' + sServerName );
PageReference retPage = new PageReference(sServerName + convertedAccountId); 
System.Debug('#######retPage :' + retPage );
retPage.setRedirect(true);


return retPage;
} 
public PageReference back(){
    String sServerName = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host');
sServerName = 'https://'+sServerName+'/';
System.Debug('#######sServerName :' + sServerName );
PageReference retPage = new PageReference(sServerName + pId); 
System.Debug('#######retPage :' + retPage );
retPage.setRedirect(true);

return retPage;
}      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Proposal p = new Proposal (p.Name = 'Test Name', p.Already_Converted__c = 'Not Converted',p.Property__c = 'a007A000001C6CM', p.Zoning__c = 'Zone',p.Lease_Type__c = 'Monthly', p.Lease_Notes__c = 'Ground Lease',p.Lot_Size__c = 100.00,p.Lot__c = 50.00,p.Cap_Rate__c = 512.75,p.Year_Built__c = '1975',p.Term__c = 456,p.NOI__c = 123.12,p.Years_Remaining__c = 10.50,p.Lease_Commencement_Date__c = date.Today(),p.Rent_Commencement_Date__c = date.Today(),p.Lease_Expiration_Date__c = date.Today(),p.Square_Footage__c = 50000),
```

You need use ; end of this statement and don't use alias inside constructor. like 'p.Name' Write only field name.

```
Proposal p = new Proposal (Name = 'Test Name', Already_Converted__c = 'Not Converted',Property__c = 'a007A000001C6CM',Zoning__c = 'Zone',Lease_Type__c = 'Monthly', Lease_Notes__c = 'Ground Lease',Lot_Size__c = 100.00,Lot__c = 50.00,Cap_Rate__c = 512.75,Year_Built__c = '1975',Term__c = 456,NOI__c = 123.12,Years_Remaining__c = 10.50,Lease_Commencement_Date__c = date.Today(),Rent_Commencement_Date__c = date.Today(),Lease_Expiration_Date__c = date.Today(),Square_Footage__c = 50000);
```

first insert p then pass p into the constructor

```
ControllerProposalConvertView cont = new ControllerProposalConvertView (p);
```

pls check out this ex [Creating Test Class for VF Page Controller](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82437/creating-test-class-for-vf-page-controller)

http://salesforcesource.blogspot.in/2008/09/geting-good-test-coverage-on-vf-pages.html